# Adding Current limit for DIY DC-DC converter (CC/CV battery charging)

Tags: battery-charging, dc-dc-converter, lithium-ion, constant-current

I was following the circuitry by great Scott for the DIY buck converter here:
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m8rK9gU30v4 .
Created a converter that gives 0-23V on 24V supply.

After this i wanted to add different current limits to this buck converter such as 1/2/3/4/5 Amps for charging different li-ion battery pack.
For that i am going to follow this"**Traditional method of implementing CC/CV**"here:

https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/powerhouse/archive/2017/11/24/how-to-design-a-simple-constant-current-constant-voltage-buck-converter

also have seen this video on adding a current limit to a buck boost converter:
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8uoo5pAeWZI

with the shunt resistor and all.

Thing is I  cannot even understand how is the **Traditional method of implementing CC/CV** working here and how to approach this software wise.

A more in depth explanation could be quite helpful and any type of suggestions regarding any other way would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current limiting is based on the fact that **I = U/R**
And the easiest way to reduce **I** (if it exceeds some *limit*) is to decrease **U** (voltage) which is what Great Scott is doing in his *hacked* video and explains it very well.

It is also important to understand how op-amps works, since they are doing all the logic here.

Typical simple DC-DC converter IC is an analog logic device. It knows nothing about what voltage on the exit now, what voltage you want to get  or what is the Current and Current limit. All it knows – is **FB** pin above or below Int. Reference voltage (e.g. **1.25 V**) at current "tick"(Note that "ticks" are mentioned for explanation only, in reality it's an analogue device and this process is continuous). If it above reference, e.g. **1.33 V** with voltage **divider 1:10**, which means **13.3 V** at output, it reduces duty cycle a little. Next tick it's **1.31 V**, reducing duty cycle again, until **FB** is below **1.25 V** (=**12.5 V**) in which case it will increase duty cycle and than decrease it...dancing around **1.25 V** reference.

As did in the video, we just put **3.3V** at **FB** pin (with additional ext. op-amp) when voltage is above some  limit, so converter will start to reduce the duty cycle and thus the output voltage each "tick", until the current will drop below set limit and our op-amp will dance around this current limit now. This called **CC** (Constant Current) mode, instead of normal **CV** (Constant Voltage) mode.

Btw, to indicate **CC** mode you can simply use current comparator's (op-amp) **3.3V** output with a capacitor, resistor and LED.

Comment: We seem to have cross-edited. "op-amp" is a contraction of "operational-amplifier" so it doesn't get capitalised.